# PowerShell Exchange 2007 Outlook 2010 Full mailbox access except 1 folder

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2007

Does any one know a way to give userA full access to userB's mailbox with the exception of one folder in the userB's mailbox using PowerShell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Add-MailboxPermission cmdlet to give full access to a mailbox and then restrict access to one mailbox folder. The Add-MailboxFolderPermission is available in Exchange 2010 and up. You could try using Exchange Web Services (EWS). Read this blog, there might be code from that script you can use.

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2008/10/exchange-reverse-permission-audit.html#!/2008/10/exchange-reverse-permission-audit.html